# "gatsby develop" error: Panicking because nodes appear to be being changed every time we run queries

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

### Description

Following error is thrown when running **gatsby develop**:

error Panicking because nodes appear to be being changed every time we run queries. This would cause the site to recompile infinitely.
Check custom resolvers to see if they are unconditionally creating or mutating nodes on every query.
This may happen if they create nodes with a field that is different every time, such as a timestamp or unique id.

I'm grateful for any help!

#### Expected result

The development environment should start

#### Actual result

Throws the following error:
error Panicking because nodes appear to be being changed every time we run queries. This would cause the site to recompile infinitely.
Check custom resolvers to see if they are unconditionally creating or mutating nodes on every query.
This may happen if they create nodes with a field that is different every time, such as a timestamp or unique id.